# Enable touch events in node webkit

Tags: ubuntu, webkit, touchscreen, touch-event, node-webkit

Im using a custom touchscreen and I want to activate by default the touch event in [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), is that possible?

[This one](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Manifest-format) tell node-webkit how to open the app and control how the browser behaves.

**Update:**

I'm using Ubuntu like OS, all functionality of touch events work like you are using a mouse(For example you need to scroll down with the scroll bar..). The question is how can I tell my OS that I need to use the mobile touch events?

Thank you.

Comment: Just I updated the post!

Answer (score 1):

Add `"chromium-args": "--touch-events",` to package.json.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and nw 0.13.04.

More information [Manifest format - chromium-args](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Manifest-format#chromium-args)